# Vue shortkeys executes in bad order

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am using iFgR/vue-shortkey module un Nuxt.js, I have a div with 3 componets, all with class pop up, the first is a from for create an object, if the object cant be created it throws an error, so the second component, that is an error pop up, must be shown, all its okay for now, but I added a shortkey for close each pop up, now the problem, when the error pop up is shown over the create pop up, I press the shortkey for close and the framework activates first the action of the shortkey in the create pop up instead of error pop up. This is a piece of code:

div with all pop ups

```
<transition-group name="fade">
  <CreateProduct v-bind:key="'createProduct'" class="pop-up" v-if="createProduct" @closeCreateProduct="createProduct=false"/>
  <ErrorPopUp v-bind:key="'errorPopUp'" class="pop-up" v-if="showError"/>
  <SuccessPopUp v-bind:key="'successPopUp'" class="pop-up" v-if="showSuccess"/>
</transition-group>
```

Create pop up

```
<template>
  <b-container fluid class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" v-shortkey.once="['esc']" @shortkey="$emit('closeCreateProduct')">
    ...
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Error pop up

```
<template>
  <b-container fluid class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" v-shortkey.once="['esc']" @shortkey="toggleShowError()">
    ...
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Ilustrative images
[Before press shortkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LkGz.png)

[After press shortkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6xqd.png)